# docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.baidubce.com/v2/"

Tags: 20.04, docker

I tried to run paddleocr through docker using this command.

```bash
sudo docker run --name ppocr -v $PWD:/paddle --network=host -it registry.baidubce.com/paddlepaddle/paddle:2.1.3-gpu-cuda10.2-cudnn7 /bin/bash
```

But I get this error

```
Unable to find image 'registry.baidubce.com/paddlepaddle/paddle:2.1.3-gpu-cuda10.2-cudnn7' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.baidubce.com/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry.baidubce.com: Temporary failure in name resolution.
```

Comment: That means that it was unable to do a DNS lookup for `registry.baidubce.com`.  That sounds like a temporary transient issue, or that your ISP is blocking traffic, or your network you're on is blocking the traffic, because it currently resolves according to Google DNS servers (US based here for the lookup).  On your command line, can you run `resolvectl query registry.baidubce.com.` and show what it says?

Comment: I got this `registry.baidubce.com: resolve call failed: Could not resolve 'registry.baidubce.com', server or network returned error SERVFAIL.`

Comment: @Trisumal That means the DNS on your network is broken.  Can you resolve something simple such as `google.com`?  `resolvectl query google.com`